# textmate $TM_SELECTED_TEXT

Tags: javascript, textmate

I'm trying to make a snippit that wraps some code around the code that I selected.

But I don't see how that can work.

If I select some code, then type in a trigger, then the code that i selected is replaced by the trigger.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.

Does this only work with key equivalent but not button triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers are 'triggered' when the tab key is hit after typing the trigger, so you can't do what you suggest no.

The proper way is to have a shortcut and then the snippet will work like you want.